# Building a graph based on another graph.

Tags: calculus

Basically, I am pretty bad with functions. My professor seems to be able to sketch the graph of 2 similar functions based on the graph of only one of them.
For example, if we have the graph of the function: $y=1/(x^2-1)$ 
how can we sketch the graph of: $y=1/(x^2-2x)$ based only on the data we have from the first graph?

Obviously, these are very similar functions so their graphs will be similar, but I don't seem to be able to visualize the difference (apart from the cases when you only change the sign of the function). Is there a trick to this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you give, note that $$
\frac{1}{x^2-2x}=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2-1}
$$
Now you should be able to see that the graph will be the same as the graph of $1/{x^2},$ except for a shift of $1$ to the right.

Comment: I see, that's a much easier way to figure it out. What about sketching the graph of $y=ln{x+2}$ if you already have the graph of $y=ln{x}$. Will it be the same graph of $y=ln{x}$, but with a shift of 2 to the left?

Comment: No, the graph will be shift *up* 2.  You have to distinguish the case where you add a number to $x$ to the case where you add a number to $y$.  However, I think your general points whether this transformation works for general functions, not just rational functions, and the answer to that is "yes".  Change $\ln x +2$ to $\ln(x+2)$.

Comment: Alright, I think i got a pretty good idea. Thank you for your hindsight.

Comment: @Teabx I hope you mean "insight," not "hindsight."

Comment: English is not my first language, so please excuse the vocabulary errors.

Comment: No apology required; I'm just trying to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

yes the trick is to find out the roots of the polynomial given below( if any) then find out the value of the function at infinity. (positive and negative both)

next find out whether the function gives postive or negative value just after the root. you will be able to get a rough sketch of the graph after this.

if i could be of any more help, feel free to comment.

Comment: I am aware of using the derivative function as a "guideline" to help you sketch the graph, what I wanted to know is what exactly happens to a graph when you change one of the variables from the original formula. For example if you know the graph of $y=x^2$ you can easily make out the graph of $y=-x^2$. But what exactly would happen to the graph if you get $y=x^2 +2x$ ? I can't really visualize that, I have to "re-calculate" the graph, and I was hoping there was some kind of trick to this.

Comment: This is certainly the way to graph a rational function, but I don't this it addresses the OP's question.  He wanted to know how to related the graph of one function to the graph of another.